# Vuejs update the state inside the other function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new to Vue.js and wanted to know how we can update the state of the component inside another function that is coming from another file. I have a simple form that only has an input file element.

When the user will select the file then the onChange handler will trigger but I don't know how to update the state inside other functions.

**Code:**

utils.js:

```
export const handleUpload = function(event, state) {
    console.log('Selected file: ', event.target.files[0]);
    // Update the selected state.
};
```

Component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input
      type="file"
      accept="image/*"
      name="photo"
      @change="onFileSelection($event)"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { handleUpload } from './utils';

export default {
  name: 'Index',
  date() {
    return {
      selected: null
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onFileSelection: handleUpload
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do it.

### Keep `handleUpload` generic and simply let it return data

You can, for example, let `handleUpload` return something that your VueJS component will use to work on further. This is so that `handleUpload` remains truly generic and does not contain any component-specific logic, since mutating a state is something specific to a component.

```
export const handleUpload = function(event) {
    console.log('Selected file: ', event.target.files[0]);
    
    return event.target.files[0];
};
```

Then in your VueJS component:

```
data() {
    return {
        selected: null
    };
},
methods: {
    onFileSelection: function(event) {
        const file = handleUpload(event);
        // Then you can change your component state here, e.g.
        this.selected = file;
    }
}
```

### Pass component into function (not recommended)

This is possible but personally I would avoid it, because it makes `handleUpload` opiniated (i.e. it needs to know what specific component data to change, and that may be different from one component to another).

```
export const handleUpload = function(event, component) {
    console.log('Selected file: ', event.target.files[0]);
    
    component.selected = event.target.files[0];'
};
```

Then in your VueJS component:

```
data() {
    return {
        selected: null
    };
},
methods: {
    onFileSelection: function(event) {
        handleUpload(event, this);
    }
}
```